# Can I combine set up and define of a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can I set up the value of a variable at the same time as I define another in JavaScript ?

```
    $scope.modal.data = {};
    $scope.modal.submitDisabled = true
```

I have these two statements. Is there a way I can combine them into one?

Comment: Okay, that's a lie, there is: `$scope.modal.submitDisabled = !!($scope.modal.data = {});` ... but do you really want code like this?

Answer (score 2):

If those two fields are the only properties (NB: not "variables") of `modal`, then sure, you can completely overwrite `$scope.modal` in one operation:

```
$scope.modal = {data: {}, submitDisabled: true};
```

If you have other fields within `modal` that you want to preserve, then no, don't bother - you'll be making your code harder to read.

That said, if you're using AngularJS (`$scope` suggests you might be) you can also do:

```
angular.extend($scope, { data: {}, submitDisabled: true} );
```

which copies the new properties into `$scope` without removing any other properties.

Comment: jQuery offers a similar extend as well.